# Parse Facebook Login not executed, PFDateFormatter unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I am building an iOS application with Parse. However when I try to log in with facebook I get the following error in the log:

```
[PFDateFormatter preciseStringFromDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x101da7628
```

The app doesn't crash, but the login just never gets executed.
It's funny because I have the exact same code for the login in another app, where it is working just fine. I triple checked all the included frameworks, my plist info for the facebook app, updated everything but still the same error.
I of course have included `[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook]` in my AppDelegate.m file and also implemented the required method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

as well as

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
[FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

Does anybody have an idea on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by making sure I had the latest version of ParseFacebookUtils framework. For some reason Cocoapods was not updating to the most recent version, maybe it was the order that I ordered the pods in? I had to uninstall the pertinent pods and then reinstall them for it to work. Here is what my podfile looks like now:

```
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
```

The pod install terminal output looks like this:

```
Using Bolts (1.1.3) 
Using Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.22.0)
Installing Parse (1.6.2) 
Installing ParseFacebookUtils (1.6.2)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution. It helped me fix the issue, too!